# How can I exit out of this loop?

Tags: java, loops, collections, hashmap, iteration

This code is trying to accept keys from user and store them onto an array of string data. Later in the program, value for each keys are displayed in some specific format.

Firstly, I want this loop to end/exit when the user input is empty/nextline. I don't want to use any EOF character or string to exit out of the loop.

I did some search on previous SO questions/solutions but didn't work in my case. Need help sorting out this problem or any other alternatives are most welcome.

Thanks in advance!

```
class DictionaryAndMap{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int len = sc.nextInt();
    Map<String, Integer> mp = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    String name;
    int phone;
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
      name = sc.next();
      phone = sc.nextInt();
      mp.put(name, phone);
    }
    int i=0;
    String arr1[] = new String[10];
    String nam;

// I couldn't exit out of this loop
   while(sc.hasNext()){
      nam = sc.next();
      if(nam!=null && !nam.trim().isEmpty()){
        arr1[i] = nam;
        i++;
      }
      else{
        break;
      }
    }

// iterating through the array to find the search inputs
    for(String j: arr1){
      if(mp.containsKey(arr1[j])){
        System.out.println(j+"="+mp.get(j));        
      }else{
        System.out.println("Not found");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**P.S.** The hasNext() value isn't changing to false even if the input is empty/null/" " therefore the while loop is never ending. How can I make the hasNext() detect any of those empty input data and therefore it could exit out of the loop?

Comment: That `else if` statement is redundant. It will always be `true` whenever the first `if` is `false`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10490358/7187887

Comment: I did come across that thread but isn't there a solution to this other than using EOF statement? Is there a way that at-least I can track \n from user input or something like that?

Comment: @Akhil Probably an explanation onto using `hasNext()` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42008037/1746118) might help.

Comment: ^ this pretty much points out my problem...may be I should try a different approach then :)

Answer (score 2):

Just check for the input being empty after you read it:

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    nam = sc.nextLine();
    if (nam.trim().isEmpty())
         break;
    ...
```

You can then simplify the rest by replacing `else if` with `else` only and remove the last `else`.

Comment: No sir. hasNext() isn't detecting empty/null user inputs. I've tried null, " " , empty...unfortunately none of those works :(

Comment: @Akhil : actually next well wait for next token, so well always return non empty string. You may want to switch to hasNextLine() and nextLine() . Scanner updated.

Comment: when I use hasNextLine(), the control is searching for input in the same line(i.e, the previous line where it takes the user input of key-value pair)...so, when I press enter after that, it's breaking the control out of the loop.

Comment: I've updated the code in the query. Please take a look into it to see why nextLine() didn't work

Answer (score 1):

you have to check the String if empty or null break so control comes out of the while loop

```
nam=sc.next();
if(name==null || name.isEmpty()){
break; //break the loop 
}
```

Comment: No sir. hasNext() isn't detecting empty/null user inputs. I've tried null, " " , empty...unfortunately none of those works :(

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the code you are looking for

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String nam;
    Map<String, Objects> mp = new HashMap<>();
    String[] arr1 = new String[1024];
    int i = 0;
    nam = sc.nextLine();

    while (nam.length() > 0) {

        if (mp.containsKey(nam)) {
            arr1[i] = nam;
            i++;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not found");
        }
        nam = sc.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Loop will be terminated by hitting enter with empty string.

Answer (score 0):

this code may help you. You no need to check **!mp.containsKey(nm)**

```
while(sc.hasNext()){
nam = sc.next();

if(mp.containsKey(nam)){
  arr1[i] = nam;
  i++;
}
else {
    System.out.println("Not found");
}
```

Comment: No way this will work. I used !mp.containsKey(nam) only because I could differentiate the empty/null input

Comment: if(mp.containsKey(nam) && !nam.trim().isEmpty()) add this one in your condition

Comment: What you actually want to do??

Comment: to be clear, I just want to exit out of that while loop when the user input is "empty" or on a simple "enter button" press

Comment: then add break; in else part